# PHP doesnt read sha1-hash (string) from array - erratic behaviour

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, sha1

I am trying to access certain subarrays of an array depending on a sha1 code saved in the subarray.
I have the following code working for me:

```
//I take a sha1 string of 40chars from GET
if(isset($_REQUEST['sha1'])){

  //then I iterate through the array and check if the subarrays sha1 matches
  for($i = 0; $i < count($scomplaints); $i++) {
    if($scomplaints[$i]['sha1'] == $_REQUEST['sha1']){

      //once a match is found I delete the match...
      unset($scomplaints[$i]);

      //... reserialize the array and update it in the database
      $new_c = serialize($scomplaints);
      // ( add new array to database )
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Pretty straight forward. Only problem is: In some random cases the loop doesnt read the sha1 value of the subarray. Instead it reads an empty string from the array.

But when i var_dump the array the sha1 code is clearly saved in the array and also identical to the one I get from GET (I did a by hand comparison).

I can't figure out what the problem is, maybe some encoding error? Maybe one of you guys can help me with this?

Thanks for all advice.

Comment: Your description of what's going wrong is very vague. What do you mean with 'Instead it gets an empty response'. What happens if you var_dump both arrays when it breaks?

Comment: Please provide cases where it breaks (array output and `GET` value).

Comment: Yeah was a bit fuzzy I updatet it but your response was way to fast for me :D Hope its clearer now.

Comment: It breaks here: array: "ab5cec9f67b5b877725a1eb4baae304f9b54cd62", sha1: "ab5cec9f67b5b877725a1eb4baae304f9b54cd62". The array value is what var_dump tells me is in the array, but the loop just returns an empty string (string length 0)

Comment: Please could you update your code above with the debug messages? Also some sample data would be helpful.

Comment: I got it solved. The issue was the array not being reindexed by unset($array). Once I reindex it with array_values($array) it works again.

Comment: @django Than publish that as your answer or close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it solved. The issue was the array not being reindexed by unset($array). Once I reindex it with array_values($array) it works again.